# Change An element in a object based on a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, state

I want to change toolbar option in remoteOptions object according to a state so that i would be able to hide and show it based on a state which changes when i click the buttons. How do i acheive this?

```
remoteOptions = {
  player: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  resizer: false,
  toolbar: {
    displayMode: false,
  },
};
<div>
  <button id="start-canvas">Start Canvas Streaming</button>
  <button id="stop-canvas">Stop Canvas Streaming</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the toolbar by modifying its styles? Can you add the code of the toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

First define the state ,
`const [show, setShow] = useState(false) ;//false` means the displayMode is false initially.

Then in **remoteOptions**,

```
 displayMode : show,
```

And then change the state on button click,

```
<button id="start-canvas" onClick={()=> setShow(true)}>Start Canvas Streaming</button>

 <button id="stop-canvas" onClick={()=> setShow(false)}> Stop Canvas Streaming</button>
```